How to ask Windows "Task Manager" to automatically maximize on startup?
I'm on Windows 11 Pro. Every time when I start "Task Manager" it'll run in a very small window and I have to click the maximize icon. How can I make it auto maximize on startup?


Task Manager will remember its last size when it was closed, and will
use it when started again. But it absolutely refuses to remember the
maximized state.
The solution is to resize Task Manager window by stretching its borders
in all directions, before closing it. It will then restart the next time
in these size and position.

Interesting! Neither making a desktop shortcut to taskmgr.exe and setting Run to Maximized, nor creating a batch file, start /MAX taskmgr.exe, will cause it to be actually maximized, i.e., full-screen, on top. Work-around: use Process Explorer, which behaves conventionally, instead ;-)

@DrMoishePippik: One can't force-maximize a window - the window is sent a message to do that itself. It seems like the startup code of taskmgr just ignores the message. This is surely a bug, and not a new one.

a bug or a feature?

weird but cool workaround. :)

I suggest to close Task Manager after resizing and restarting, again, manually. I remember that the new settings were not persisted when Task Manager was closed, automatically during restart.

You can create your own hotkey.
Go to "C:\Some\Path" where you want your script to be, i named it TaskMax.ps1
and in it placed;
Start-Process -FilePath "taskmgr.exe" -WindowStyle Maximized

Save, and close script.

Now I went to my;
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility

1st create shortcut there, use RMB pick New -> Shortcut .
It doesnt matter what you input here for path, we will edit it in a minute, name it as you wish.
2nd open Properties for that shortcut

Now here edit your Target to;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "C:\Some\Path\TaskMax.ps1"

Then place Shortcut key to anything you like, I used Ctrl + Shift + 1 .
save, and press to :)
P.S. You can Disable or Enable Ctrl+shift+ESC behavior, you can not change or mod it in any other manner.

cool. can avoid creating the .ps1 file with powershell.exe -c "Start-Process -FilePath taskmgr.exe -WindowStyle Maximized".

True, could avoid whole ps1 part, tho script expands what user can do with shortcut keypress.
